# Sobel Operator not working

Tags: java, arrays, image-processing, matrix, computer-vision

I've been spending the last two hours on it and didn't realize where the problem is, would you help me out?

```
public static void sobel(Img img) {

    int[][][] myArray = img.getmyArray();
    int[][][] sobelX = img.copyMyArray();
    int[][][] sobelY = img.copyMyArray();

    //itearates through the matrix to apply the Sobel Operator
    for (int line = 1; line < myArray.length -2; line++)
        for (int column = 1; column < myArray[line].length -2; column++)
            for(int color = 0; color < 3; color++){

            sobelX[line][column][color] =
                    -1 * myArray[line-1][column-1][color] +
                    -2 * myArray[line-1][column][color] +
                    -1 * myArray[line-1][column+1][color] +

                     0 * myArray[line][column-1][color] +
                     0 * myArray[line][column][color] +
                     0 * myArray[line][column+1][color] +

                     1 * myArray[line+1][column-1][color] +
                     2 * myArray[line+1][column][color] +
                     1 * myArray[line+1][column+1][color];

            sobelY[line][column][color] =
                    -1 * myArray[line-1][column-1][color] +
                     0 * myArray[line-1][column][color] +
                     1 * myArray[line-1][column+1][color] +

                    -2 * myArray[line][column-1][color] +
                     0 * myArray[line][column][color] +
                     2 * myArray[line][column+1][color] +

                    -1 * myArray[line+1][column-1][color] +
                     0 * myArray[line+1][column][color] +
                     1 * myArray[line+1][column+1][color];


            //Final Calculation
            myArray[line][column][color] = check_0_255_limit((int)Math.sqrt(
                    sobelX[line][column][color] * sobelX[line][column][color]
                    +
                    sobelY[line][column][color] * sobelY[line][column][color]
                    ));

        }// end for loop
}
```

No error messages, the code is compiling and running, but I'm getting a bad output, it is not what I expected..
[image: Sobel Operator]

Comment: -1 No error messages, no useful clues, not a single useful comment in the code.

Comment: The issue seems to be that there is no question in your question.

Comment: Actually the question seems to be: "Would you help me out?" to which my answer would be: "Sure, what is the problem?"

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating the gradients for each channel independently; do you really need to, as your output isn't in colour?
Also the output of the operator, given 0..255 channel value inputs, would be -1020..1020 so you need to scale it before or after getting the magnitude with the Sqrt, to get it back to the 0..255 range.

But the main problem is probably that the "final calculation" output overwrites the array you are looping over (i.e. the filter is reprocessing already-processed values) so put that in its own array. This is what gives the cool dithering effect!

Comment: Sorry wasn't aware that the question "cannot be reasonably answered in its current form", pretty sure I understood it!!